# Can value of associatedType be a protocol?

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

Can the value of a associatedtype be a protocol?

```
protocol A {
    var name: String {get set}
}

protocol B: A {}

protocol C {
    associatedtype T: B
    var t : T {get set}
}

class D : C {
    var t : B

    init(t : B) {
        self.t = t
    }
}

class E : B {
    var name: String = ""
}

class F : B {
    var name: String = "ff"
}
```

In class D, if the type of t is E or F, the code compiles. But if the type of t is B(which is a protocol), compilation fails stating:

> Type 'D' does not conform to protocol 'C'

How can I have an associated type to hold a protocol value? Any pointers to why it is failing?

**Updated question**

Removing bound on associatedtype and having just T will not help. My protocol also has methods on it which I want to access. For example:

```
protocol A {
    func sayHello()
}

protocol B : A  {
    var name: String {get set}
}

extension B {
    func sayHello() {
        print("Hello")
    }
}

protocol C {
    associatedtype T
    var t: T {get set}
}

class D : C {
    typealias T = E
    var t: T

    init(t : T) {
        self.t = t
    }
}

class E : B {
    var name: String = ""
}

class F : B {
    var name: String = "ff"
}

class G<S: C> {
    var a: S

    init(a: S) {
        self.a = a
    }

    func notWorking() {
        a.t.sayHello()
    }
}
```

In the above example, I am not able to access sayHello method.

Comment: [Protocols don't always conform to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/2976878) – `B` is not a type that conforms to `B`, so cannot satisfy the associated type `associatedtype T: B`.

Answer (score 1):

[Generic Protocols with Associated Type](https://blog.bobthedeveloper.io/generic-protocols-with-associated-type-7e2b6e079ee2)

```
protocol C {
    associatedtype T
    var t : T {get set}
}
```

anything that conforms to C must implement `associatedtype T` . However, the type is not defined. Therefore, the class or struct that conforms to the protocol must define it either implicitly or explicitly.

First, let’s create a class SomeClass that conforms to C. We must define `t`. Well, You may define `t` based on the value associated with `T`.

```
class D : C {

    typealias T = B
    var t: B

    init(t : B) {
        self.t = t
    }
}
```

**Update**

You have created T `associatedtype`, means assign a dynamically generic type value, in this case, `T` value is already assigned. why are you creating an associatedtype, you can use directly. like

```
protocol C {
    //associatedtype T: B 
    //var t : T {get set}

    var t: B {get set} // write directly.
}
```

Comment: In the above implementation, basically we are removing the upper bound while defining the associatedType. But this means that we can not access any methods that are defined inside the protocol.

Comment: @Sajani check out my updated answer